# NoSuchElementException is occurred during implementation of InternetExplorerDriver in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

Currently, I am working on WebDriver to invoke IE browser to run the testing. But I received a `NoSuchElementException` when I tried to run the simple example below.

However, the code just worked fine if I used Chrome Driver or Firefox driver.
Any idea or thought would be appreciated.

Jar: `selenium-server-standalone-2.5.0.jar`

Code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
  ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
  WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);
  driver.get("www.google.com");
  driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
}
```

Error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with name == q (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.5.0', revision: '13516', time: '2011-08-23 18:29:57'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_25'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:105)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:409)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:197)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByName(RemoteWebDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByName.findElement(By.java:298)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:189)
    at lib.WebDriver2.main(WebDriver2.java:14)
```

Comment: That stacktrace/error message looks incomplete, are you sure that it's complete?

Comment: Hi, updated the error message :) IE browser was opened and directed to google page. But, it failed as it tried to find the element "q"

Comment: same issue here. I'm using a 64bit system, but with a 32 bit jvm, so the driver is 32 bit too. Nothing listed below helped

Comment: You've explicitly avoided having to set the Protected Mode settings of IE. That's what the `InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS` capability setting does. What happens if you remove this capability setting and set the Protected Mode settings as documented in the [project wiki](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver)?

Comment: Hi JimEvans, Thanks a lot for your help!! I removed the "ieCapabilities". Instead, I went to Internet option and followed the steps as Project Wiki. It works for me right now. The most important information is "you must set the Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value."  Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: Great. Promoting this comment to an answer, so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've explicitly avoided having to set the Protected Mode settings of IE. That's what the `InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS` capability setting does. When you remove this capability setting and set the Protected Mode settings as documented in the [project wiki](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver), it seems the problem resolves itself.

Comment: Hi Jim. Thanks for the solution. I do not have any privileges to modify the security settings. Is there a workaround? Thanks!

Comment: The capability **is** the workaround. [This blog post](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html) describes the technical reasons why the Protected Mode settings matter and why your organization is actively sabotaging your ability to get your work done if they don't allow you to change the setting.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding implicitly wait like below. Also as Robert said, your URL should have http://

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Hi Nilesh, Thanks a lot for your help. But, the solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: Thats because you should use FluentWait instead with an .ignoring clause to recover from exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

There was a short [FAQ entry](https://web.archive.org/web/20151018011652/https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_The_does_not_work_well_on_Vista._How_do_I_get_it_to_work_as_e) on the project website (copied circa Selenium 2.9):

> The InternetExplorerDriver requires that all security domains are set
>   to the same value (either trusted or untrusted) If you're not in a
>   position to modify the security domains, then you can override the
>   check like this:
>
> ```
> DesiredCapabilities capabilities =
> DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
> capabilities.set(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
> true); 
> WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
> ```
>
> As can be told by the name of the constant, this may introduce flakiness
>   in your tests. If all sites are in the same protection domain, you
>   should be okay.

The parallel C# InvalidOperationException message:

> Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode must be
>   set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones.
>   (NoSuchDriver)

and the C# instead of adjusting IE settings (best guess as of Feb 2016):

```
var ieOptions = new OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerOptions {
                IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true };
using (var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions))
{
```

This was all part of [issue 1795](https://web.archive.org/web/20140522001425/http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1795) on the Selenium issue tracker.

Comment: For C# version, I am not able to pass a DesiredCapabilities in InternetExplorerDriver constructor