# Selenium IEDriver issue launching IE NoSuchWindowException

Tags: java, windows, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)Command duration or timeout: 16 millisecondsBuild info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 21:08:56'System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_07'Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriverSession ID: c1d95c8f-b182-4f96-a9f9-ed67f68b0bc9Command duration or timeout: 190 millisecondsBuild info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 22:18:01'System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.7.4', java.version: '1.6.0_33'Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriverSession ID: 1347289084315at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
 java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:188)
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:498)
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:502)
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getPageSource(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:229)
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:121)
 com.pearson.moxie.schooladmin.LoginTests.startSelenium(LoginTests.groovy:59)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
 org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
 org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
 org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
 org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
 org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
 org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
 org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
 org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
 org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
 org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
 org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
 org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
 org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
 org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
 org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
 org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:45)
 org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
 org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
 org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
 org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
 org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:123)
 org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:195)
 org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAllProviders(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:177)
 org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:135)
 org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:98)
 org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions(MojoExecutor.java:365)
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:199)
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
 org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
 org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
 org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
 org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
 org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
 org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
 org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
 org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ScreenshotException: Screen shot has been takenBuild info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 22:18:01'System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.7.4', java.version: '1.6.0_33'Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriverat org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:125)... 73 moreCaused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)Command duration or timeout: 16 millisecondsBuild info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 21:08:56'System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_07'Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriverSession ID: c1d95c8f-b182-4f96-a9f9-ed67f68b0bc9Build info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 22:18:01'System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.7.4', java.version: '1.6.0_33'Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriverat sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:188)
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:498)
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:502)
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getPageSource(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2.invoke(EventFiringWebDriver.java:101)
 $Proxy1.getPageSource(Unknown Source)
 org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.getPageSource(EventFiringWebDriver.java:186)
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.GetPageSource.call(GetPageSource.java:29)
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.GetPageSource.call(GetPageSource.java:1)
 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:150)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is how we are setting up our driver:

```
DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
ieCapabilities.setCapability( InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true );
ieCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);

driver = new RemoteWebDriver( new URL( "http://" + serverIp + ":" + serverPort + "/wd/hub" ), ieCapabilities );
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
```

We execute:

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
```

It successfully navigates to google.com and then throws this stacktrace on the next selenium or webdriver api call :/

We are using Windows 7, ie 8 with RemoteWebDriver 2.25.0 and IEDriver.exe

Comment: it was the internet security settings >_<. I set all zones of protected mode to off and it works now

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium Web Driver: InternetExplorerDriver : NoSuchElementException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278340/selenium-web-driver-internetexplorerdriver-nosuchelementexception)

Comment: @jkieley You should accept any of the expected answer or add your own.

Answer (score 3):

IE settings must be modified as give in the [link](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver)

On IE 7 or higher on Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must set the Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value. The value can be on or off, as long as it is the same for every zone. To set the Protected Mode settings, choose "Internet Options..." from the Tools menu, and click on the Security tab. For each zone, there will be a check box at the bottom of the tab labeled "Enable Protected Mode".

Then use the code as below

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.set(InternetExplorerDriver.
                 INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true); 
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: I am using IE 11 and the above code is not working for me. I am getting  org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find element on closed window (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Answer (score 0):

This topic has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278340/selenium-web-driver-internetexplorerdriver-nosuchelementexception)

So try this setting for the driver:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.set(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
true); 
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```

That worked for me