# How to ignore zoom setting

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

IE ignore zoom setting doesn't work, my code as below, why it doesn't work? I got the error message (selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Browser zoom level was set to 125%. It should be set to 100%)

```
from selenium.webdriver import Ie
from selenium.webdriver.ie.options import Options
opts = Options()
opts.ignore_protected_mode_settings = True
driver = Ie(options=opts)
```

Comment: Try this, using desired caps ignore zoom setting 
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING, true);

WebDriver driver= new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);

once page has been successfully loaded change zoom level using 
driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"0"));

Comment: Thanks, but I use python language.

Comment: @sandeepraulo What can be a valid usecase to configure the _WebDriver_ instance to **ignore** the zoom settings while initialization only to change it later during the _Tests_?

Comment: @DebanjanB I tried an example from my end where even after ignoring the zoom settings selenium code was throwing either nosuchelementexception or window not in focus exception so i just tried an the mentioned code where post driver initialization it will make zoom settings to 100%.

Comment: @SandeepRaulo If you refer to my Answer about the documentation for _Required Configuration of  InternetExplorerDriver_ mentioned in my Answer _ignoring the zoom_ will induce much havoc through different errors such as nosuchelementexception, window not in focus, etc. It's always better to follow the _Best Practices_ documented by the _IE_ team. In case you have any questions feel free to raise a ticket, SO volunteers will be glad to help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, while working with **InternetExplorerDriver** you shouldn't ignore the browser zoom settings.

As per the Official Documentation of *InternetExplorerDriver* the [**`Required Configuration`**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration) mentions the following about **Browser Zoom Level**

```
The browser zoom level must be set to 100% so that the native mouse events can be set to the correct coordinates.
```

As the browser zoom level is set to **125%** hence you see the error. As a solution you must set the browser zoom level back to **100%**.

---

### Update

Though you havn't replied/commented to my Answer which was constructed as per your question I can observe from your question update that you are trying to set the property **ignore_protected_mode_settings** to **True**. To achieve that you need to use an instance of **DesiredCapabilities()** Class and configure the *WebDriver* instance as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

cap = DesiredCapabilities().INTERNETEXPLORER
cap['ignoreZoomSetting'] = True
browser = webdriver.Ie(capabilities=cap, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\IEDriverServer.exe')
browser.get('http://google.com/')
browser.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer, but I still got the same error "selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Browser zoom level was set to 125%. It should be set to 100%" with your code.

Comment: @Johnny The error is quite clear **zoom level was set to 125%. It should be set to 100%**. Our attempt to `ignoreZoomSetting` failed. That is what I emphasized to you in the first part of my Answer.

Comment: Got it. thanks, I set zoom setting  to 100% to avoid this error by manually. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue. The option `ignore_zoom_level` solved it.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.ie.options import Options


ie_options = Options()
ie_options.ignore_zoom_level = True
ie_driver = webdriver.Ie(options=ie_options)
```

See also: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/driver_idiosyncrasies/driver_specific_capabilities/#internet-explorer