# Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned HRESULT 80070002

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

I am facing below error when i run the selenium from gocd server to window server via ssh .

> Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned
>   HRESULT 80070002 ('The system cannot find the file specified.') for
>   URL 'http://localhost:9516/' (WARNING: The server did not provide any
>   stacktrace information)

but it working fine if i run same script in windows server itself.

Configuration:
- selenium version : 3.11
- IE browser version : 11.09
- OS : Windows server 2012 R12
- IE  32 driver version : 3.14
 
(I tried in lower version also 2.14 also)

same [script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6StR.png) is working fine for chrome..

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6djfY.png)

Note: i configured already IE zoom settings, protected mode ...

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165929/unexpected-error-launching-internet-explorer-ielaunchurl-returned-hresult-800) helps you?

Comment: i tried Antonio.. but it didnt helped me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in NodeJS that I resolved.  (I know this is old but I wanted to post in case someone else runs into this issue)

Not sure how your environment is configured, but for me using [ServiceBuilder.setEnvironment](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/remote/index_exports_DriverService.Builder.html) caused this issue.  When I let WebDriver inherit the current environment everything runs fine.

If you're not using a custom environment I would ensure that your PATH variables are set correctly and that you can run Internet explorer from a command prompt by typing 'iexplore' indicating it's in your PATH properly.