# How to run IE with VBA using Selenium

Tags: vba, selenium, internet-explorer

How to overcome the IE Zoom Problem when launching it from VBA using Selenium? I have found only some code for other languages, but could not find anything for VBA.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can't use Selenium IEDriver if you don't set IE zoom level to 100%. One of the [required configuration](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration) of using Selenium IEDriver is that:

> The browser zoom level **must be set to 100%** so that the native mouse events can be set to the correct coordinates.

Only with the zoom level set to 100% then we can launch IE from VBA using Selenium.

Reference link: [How to ignore zoom setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788994/how-to-ignore-zoom-setting)

---

**Edit:**

If you have opened IE through Selenium VBA then you could use the following code to zoom in the webpage:

```
driver.ExecuteScript "document.body.style.zoom='200%';"
```

Comment: I've managed to open the IE - thank you. Now I would need something to ignore the zoom level as everything is super small. How can I zoom the page back and keep Selenium work (or will it brake?). The linked question is about the error itself which is no longer a problem for me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ok, I've just used Send Keys. I hope it's a good way to do so.

Comment: From your last comment, it seems that you have fixed the issue. Based on your explanation in the comment, I also updated my answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try such code

```
Sub Test()
    Dim bot As New IEDriver
    With bot
        .Get "https://www.google.co.uk"
        .Window.Maximize
        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you install selenium properly? Review this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216623/)

Comment: The linked question is about Chrome - for me it's working with Chrome, so not quite sure.

Comment: The code is working for me. I have windows 10 64 Bit and Internet Explorer 11 and Office 365 32 Bit .. Make sure the IE is installed correctly.