# selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Timed out waiting for page to load using IEDriverServer and Internet Explorer through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, selenium-iedriver

Given this code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# import org.openqa.selenium.Keys
import datetime
import time
import unittest

cap = DesiredCapabilities().INTERNETEXPLORER
cap['ignoreProtectedModeSettings'] = True
cap['IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings'] = True
cap['nativeEvents'] = True
cap['ignoreZoomSetting'] = True
cap['requireWindowFocus'] = True
cap['INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS'] = True
browser = webdriver.Ie(capabilities=cap, executable_path=r'C:\IEDriverServer_x64_3.150.1\IEDriverServer.exe')
browser.get("https://www.google.ro/?safe=active&ssui=on")
search_form = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/button[1]')
search_form.click()
```

When I run it, for every try, on any website this error is returned :

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Timed out waiting for page to load.
```

Running the same code on a different PC works fine, in my case I want the test to fail with element not found, given the xpath specified is wrong.

The process is "stuck" at

```
browser.get("https://www.google.ro/?safe=active&ssui=on")
```

as if the page didn't load properly.

I am using python 3.8.0
IEDriverServer_x64_3.150.1 selenium driver

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Timed out waiting for page to load.
```

...implies that the *IEDriverServer* executable binary was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Internet Explorer Browsing* session.

---

As per the [Required Configuration](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration) of [Internet Explorer Driver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#internet-explorer-driver):

### Protected Mode

On Internet Explorer 7 or higher on Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must set the **Protected Mode** settings for each zone to be the same value. The value can be on or off, as long as it is the same for every zone. To set the **Protected Mode settings** you have to choose "Internet Options" from the "Tools" menu and then click on the *Security tab*. For each zone, there will be a check box at the bottom of the tab labeled **Enable Protected Mode**.

[image: ProtectedModeSettings]

Additionally, `@JimEvans` in his article [**You're Doing It Wrong: IE Protected Mode and WebDriver**](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.in/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html) clearly mentions :

> *Using the capability doesn't solve the underlying problem though. If a Protected Mode boundary is crossed, very unexpected behavior including hangs, element location not working, and clicks not being propagated, could result. To help warn people of this potential problem, the capability was given big scary-sounding names like `INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS` in *Java* and `IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings` in *.NET*. We really thought that telling the user that using this setting would introduce potential badness in their code would discourage its use, but it turned out not to be so.*

---

### Solution

To access the url `https://www.google.ro/?safe=active&ssui=on` using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [selenium-iedriver](/questions/tagged/selenium-iedriver) initiated [internet-explorer](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer) *Browsing Context* you can use the following minimal code block:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\IEDriverServer.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.ro/?safe=active&ssui=on')
```

---

### Additional Considerations

Ensure the following steps:

- Upgrade *JDK* to  current levels [JDK 8u251](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- Upgrade *IEDriverServer* to  latest [IEDriverServer v3.150.1](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.150/) level.

> **Note**: As per *best practices* as *Selenium Client* and *InternetExplorerDriver* are released in sync and you must try to use both the binaries from the same **major** release.

- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Internet Explorer Protective mode setting and Zoom levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49850465/internet-explorer-protective-mode-setting-and-zoom-levels/49851282#49851282)
- [How to ignore protected Mode Settings for Internet Explorer using setCapability() through Selenium and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51729275/how-to-ignore-protected-mode-settings-for-internet-explorer-using-setcapability/51734556#51734556)
- [How to ignore zoom setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788994/how-to-ignore-zoom-setting/49789100#49789100)