# Internet Explorer 11 getting stuck randomly while executing tests through IEDriverServer and Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, internet-explorer-11, selenium-iedriver

I'm having issues that IE version 11 stuck randomly on some page. the code is working fine because whenever i restart the program sometimes it work but the most annoying will be randomly stuck after click and load the page. is this normal on IE? i never had this type of issues when using Chrome. but this website works only at IE. can i know the cause of this problem is it the driver?, the website itself? or Network security?

Comment: Although sometimes selenium's output script can't work well with some problem such as floating layer, ng-click or something else such as this page haven't complete initialization and if one step is broken, the script will stuck , but you said that `the code is working fine`. So I suggest it will be IE's problem.  I suggest you can show the problem more clearly or try firefox.

Comment: That's because the IE driver. I wouldn't use selenium when I automate IE, I use watir-classic which uses win32ole implementation which outstandingly does the Job even though this Ruby gem is deprecated.

Comment: @Rajagopalan This is not the first comment I’ve seen you make where you explicitly blame the IE driver for being substandard in some general, non-specific way. It would be great if you could be more specific in your criticism, or even better, help fix whatever you think is wrong with the driver.

Comment: @JimEvans Its deadly slow, in my environment, selecting an option refreshes the page, it selects the option but at the end it throws the error that object is disabled. I hear from my colleague saying it would not excute JavaScript properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you work with *Internet Explorer v11* you need to configure your *test framework* with the [Required Configuration](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver). Apart from these specifically ***only for IE 11*** you will need to set a *registry entry* on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of *Internet Explorer* it creates as follows:

- For 32-bit Windows installations, the key you must examine in the registry editor is:

  ```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE.
  ```
- For 64-bit Windows installations, the key is:

  ```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE.
  ```

---

### Trivia

- [How does the registry entry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\…\FEATURE_BFCACHE for InternetExplorerDriver solves the Internet Explorer 11 issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51600120/how-does-the-registry-entry-hkey-local-machine-feature-bfcache-for-internete)
- [Internet Explorer Protective mode setting and Zoom levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49850465/internet-explorer-protective-mode-setting-and-zoom-levels)
- [Selenium InternetExplorerDriver doesn't get focus on the window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726121/selenium-internetexplorerdriver-doesnt-get-focus-on-the-window)
- [How to ignore protected Mode Settings for Internet Explorer using setCapability() through Selenium and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51729275/how-to-ignore-protected-mode-settings-for-internet-explorer-using-setcapability)

Comment: Lifesaver@DebanjanB