# Selenium Web driver IE 11

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

I am new to selenium and trying to execute my selenium web-driver script on IE 11 with window 10 combination  sometime its run really slow and most of the time test fails with exceptions.

Exception:

```
System info: host: 'REF16U1ABJUN', ip: '172.17.2.130', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
```

Upgraded Selenium to current levels Version 3.141.59.
Upgraded IEDriverServer to latest IEDriverServer v3.150.1

Can somebody help me.

Comment: Which version of IE 11 do you have? There might be more stable combinations of IE 11 and the IEDriverServer.

Comment: you need to post the actual exception here...

Comment: System info: host: 'REF16U1ABJUN', ip: '172.17.2.130', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'

Comment: Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: internet explorer, browserVersion: 11, javascriptEnabled: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy()

Comment: se:ieOptions: {browserAttachTimeout: 0, elementScrollBehavior: 0, enablePersistentHover: true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches: , ie.edgechromium: false, ie.edgepath: , ie.ensureCleanSession:

Comment: Thank you for responding back to me those are exception i am getting after running my script i did disable protected mode setting for all zones.and try to use different IE driver versions but nothing works for me could you please guide me if i am missing something,IE 11 version is 64 bit i did try both IE driver 32 or 64 Thank you

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55285722/what-is-the-correct-iedriverserver-version-to-use-with-ie-11-through-selenium) SO can help you.

Comment: Please check your code, perhaps you are using the SendKeys method to enter values, if that is the case, you could try to use the `ExecuteScript()` method to execute the JavaScript script and use it to enter values into the input text element. More detail information, please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430773/how-to-use-javascript-with-selenium-webdriver-java).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue that test cases were slow on IE.

> A quick solution is to use Internet explorer driver of 32 bit instead
>   64 bit.

Still if you facing slowness of IE 11 after switched to IE driver 32 bit then keep [these points](https://softwaretestingboard.com/q2a/258/ie-11-is-too-slow#axzz6BJdkGak5) in mind.

[Recommendation for IE driver 32 bit](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-run-webdriver-in-ie-browser)

You can download IE driver from [here](https://selenium.dev/downloads/)

**Update: Try this**

> Internet Options
>   → Advanced → Security → ☑ Enable 64-bit processes for Enhanced
>   Protected Mode

Comment: Hi,thank you for responding back to me . I am using  IE 11 version with 64 bit i did try to use IE driver version 32 bit still facing  same issue do you have any more suggestions on this issue thank you

Comment: I have added points have details specific to IE10-11 to improve speed like disable protected mode. Zoom level should be 100% and change in reg entry for IE-11 specific please check these points hyperlink

Comment: “Enhance protected mode” must be disabled. Is it done?

Comment: @Mirfan I have updated the question. Please try it

Comment: yes they are disable for all zones

Comment: Can you try updated part of post.

Comment: hi i just disable enhanced protected mode setting with zones setting let see if it works for me

Comment: I am talking about ‘Enhance Protected mode’ which in advance tab not ‘Enable protected mode’ which is in security tab