# How to ignore protected Mode Settings for Internet Explorer using setCapability() through Selenium and Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver, mutablecapabilities

I am trying to test in java selenium with IE but my problem is I have to keep on configuring the settings in protected Mode, is the an alternative to the deprecated
function

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);
```

As I would like to have this automated without human interaction. I am using this code in eclipse and it has no effect at all in my code the above is stroked out with a yellow line highlighter and that says it has been deprecated. So is there a new function to achieve this here is the code I have been using just for sanity check

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
cap.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
cap.setCapability("unexpectedAlertBehaviour", "accept");
cap.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
cap.setCapability("disable-popup-blocking", true);
cap.setCapability("enablePersistentHover", true);
cap.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you were almost there. You need to use the method [**`merge()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions.html#merge-org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities-) from [**MutableCapabilities**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html) Class to merge the *DesiredCapabilities* type of object into *InternetExplorerOptions* type object and initiate the *WebDriver* and *WebClient* instance by passing the *InternetExplorerOptions* object as follows :

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
cap.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
cap.setCapability("unexpectedAlertBehaviour", "accept");
cap.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
cap.setCapability("disable-popup-blocking", true);
cap.setCapability("enablePersistentHover", true);
cap.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.merge(cap);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer from **DebanjanB**, this was what I required. But I was getting some error on `DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();` part, here is what worked for me:

```
     InternetExplorerOptions cap = new InternetExplorerOptions();
     cap.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
     cap.setCapability("unexpectedAlertBehaviour", "accept");
     cap.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
     cap.setCapability("disable-popup-blocking", true);
     cap.setCapability("enablePersistentHover", true);
     cap.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
     cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
     WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);
```