# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Failed to navigate to "....". This usually means that a call to the COM method IWebBrowser2::Navigate2() failed

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, exception, selenium-webdriver, iedriverserver

Trying to open Explorer on a remote server by calling 'new InternetExplorerDriver() in C#'. I have opened the task manager to check if it opens explorer. And I do see the IEDriver(32 bit) and Explorer running in the background processes. But it raises an exception when I tried to open a link by setting 'driver.Url'.
It works fine for the other browsers (chrome, firefox). But fails for Explorer.

I have tried the answer that was marked right at
  [IE11 Selenium WebDriverException: Failed to navigate. (org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException ...IWebBrowser2::Navigate2() failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32119931/ie11-selenium-webdriverexception-failed-to-navigate-org-openqa-selenium-webdr?lq=1)

The 32 bit bit IEDriver works fine in my local machine. But when I tried this on a remote server, it failed. I have tried it with both 64 bit and 32 bit IEDrivers on the server. I get the same exception.

I have also tried by setting the security zones to same level (Internet Options).

Could you suggest me some solutions, that you have tried?.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and the error stack trace.